# deleting lines from a text file with bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have two sets of text files. First set is in AA folder. Second set is in BB folder. The content of ff.txt file from first set(AA folder) is shown below.

```
Name        number     marks
john            1         60
maria           2         54
samuel          3         62
ben             4         63
```

I would like to print the second column(number) from this file if marks>60. The output will be 3,4. Next, read the ff.txt file in BB folder  and delete the lines containing numbers 3,4. How can I do this with bash?

files in BB folder looks like this. second column is the number.

```
   marks       1      11.824  24.015  41.220  1.00 13.65 
   marks       1      13.058  24.521  40.718  1.00 11.82
   marks       3      12.120  13.472  46.317  1.00 10.62 
   marks       4      10.343  24.731  47.771  1.00  8.18
```

Comment: Shouldn't the output be 3,4, since only 62 and 63 are greater than 60?

Comment: I would use awk to filter the output ... Have you considered that?

Comment: what does the file in the BB folder look like? Is it exactly the same as the one in AA?

Comment: Awk should be a good idea. I would use a temporary file where I would stock every entry that is bigger than 60 and then remove those lines with awk in the second directory.

Comment: you're getting there. Now we need to see your required output, and the code you are using and why it is not working, using the real error messages produced by your system. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but is not efficient (is that matter?)

```
gawk 'BEGIN {getline} $3>60{print $2}' AA/ff.txt | while read number; do gawk -v number=$number '$2 != number' BB/ff.txt > /tmp/ff.txt; mv /tmp/ff.txt BB/ff.txt; done
```

Of course, the second awk can be replaced with sed -i

---

For multi files:

```
ls -1 AA/*.txt | while read file
do
    bn=`basename $file`
    gawk 'BEGIN {getline} $3>60{print $2}' AA/$bn | while read number
    do
        gawk -v number=$number '$2 != number' BB/$bn > /tmp/$bn
        mv /tmp/$bn BB/$bn
    done
done
```

I didn't test it, so if there is a problem, please comment.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly for single file. But for multiple files , I am getting error like this "mv: target `BB/hh.txt' is not a directory".How to change your code for running with multiple files?

Comment: gawk 'BEGIN {getline} $3>60{print $2}' AA/*.txt | while read number; do gawk -v number=$number '$2 != number' BB/*.txt > /tmp/*.txt; mv /tmp/*.txt BB/*.txt; done  what is the mistake?

Comment: This won't work anyway because the awk will work on all .txt files in dir AA at once. I will post a new answer

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'FNR == NR && $3 > 60 {array[$2] = 1; next} {if ($2 in array) next; print}' AA/ff.txt BB/filename
```